# Using system password to serve as a password for an application

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use the users system password to serve as the password for an application I am creating. I have researched uac functions but none of that is really helping me. Any ideas on where i should look next?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`System.DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace contained in System.DirectoryServices.dll to authenticate the user using Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't recall the password of the currently logged in user. What you do is trust the identity of the person, since they've already been authenticated.